# What's the effective difference between redirecting to /dev/null and simply closing the stream

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

Background:
I want to test some bash scripts in a modified environment with a restricted bash. In a restricted bash I am not allowed to redirect a stream to a file e.g. `2>/dev/null`
I found a workaround by simply closing the stream with e.g. `2>&-`

While trying here and there I found no effective difference between `2>/dev/null` and `2>&-`
The STDERR output is swallowed up and doesn't appear.

```
$ bash -c 'ls FOO'
ls: cannot access FOO: No such file or directory
$ bash -c 'ls FOO 2>/dev/null'
$ bash -rc 'ls FOO 2>/dev/null'
bash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
$ bash -rc 'ls FOO 2>&-'
$ bash -rc 'ls FOO 2>&- ; ls BAR'
ls: cannot access BAR: No such file or directory
```

I guess the processing inside bash is different but that's not important to me. What IS important to me, is can the general closing instead of redirecting to /dev/null cause any problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends upon what the program is doing.

If you [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), then a future [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) would re-use the same file descriptor. Also, future [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (without any `open`) would fail with `EINVAL`.

Most programs don't bother to check if e.g. [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) succeeded (in theory, they should).

If you successfully redirect to `/dev/null` [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is always successful. Read [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html).

I recommend redirecting to `/dev/null` when possible.

Comment: okay so basically if I invoke a program and close STDERR, the program could see that a write / printf etc. fails? Thank you for your detailed answer, it helped me very much